# Would a c++ class/struct be noticeably slower than a c-array in heavy simulation codes

Tags: c++, c, arrays, performance, struct

Creating a data class/struct is said to be slower than a c-array due to addition of "different levels of indirection" and is apparently 'false' as found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/46935/).  I've been working on a simulation code for awhile and, although I know people always say to not pre-optimize, knowing what data structures to use is essential before you get in too deep.

If I am going to run >10,000 main loops with anywhere from 1->50 'mini-loops' and maybe even 1->10 'mini-mini-loops' (ie, a maximum of say ~10,000,000 loops in total), would it be beneficial to keep all my data in c code? Or is the difference in speed insignificant enough that I can utilize classes so as to not write one large c file?

Comment: Can you give an example of two snippets whose compared performance you're interested in?

Comment: Sadly I can't.  It's confidential work for my independent study (I'm an Undergrad).  But I can say that the original code can run 10,000 main loops with an initial "energy" of 100 or 100,000 and will take 5 minutes and 24 hours respectively, so I've been trying to optimize it as best as I can.

Edit - Original code was written >10 years ago too

Comment: *is said to be slower* please give evidence for this statement. Who said that? Was it supported by data? >10 years ago, most compilers had difficulty to achieve the same level of optimisation, but today there are absolutely not differences in performance, AFAIK.

Comment: You don't have to put your actual code (few people do; we all have privacy/contractual concerns). But you always can post representative snippets of code so that we can better help you. Otherwise we are all guessing.

Comment: Of course depending from what you do in those cycles anything can happen, but they  sound a bit too slow to me... Did you enable the optimizations of your compiler? What compiler are you using?

Comment: @hherbol When you profiled the original code, how much time did you determine was spent accessing data compared to doing all the other math, etc., that your simulation is doing? Where was your actual bottleneck? What about in your new code? Also it may be worth noting that there's zero difference between a "C array" and a "C++ array".

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Also, the original code isn't mine and is well over 5 thousand lines of code in fortran (a language I'm not too confident in).  In terms of bottlenecking, I'm still unsure as to where that may be, though I think having re-read through the code it might be due to the original one writing to files in each loop, instead of batch writing every, say, 50 loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you use virtual functions or virtual base classes, there should be absolutely no difference in the generated code. In C++, there is no run-time difference whatsoever between class and struct; the only difference has to do with member visibility, which is purely compile-time.

It's not clear from the question how you are comparing a C++ class with a C array. C has struct and C++ has arrays, and in general terms, using arrays in C and using arrays in C++ will produce identical results, and similarly with "POD" (plain old data) classes (aside from C++-only features as mentioned above.)

You might possibly be thinking about the difference between C++ `std::vector` versus C arrays. A `std::vector` does involve an indirection, although in many cases the optimizer will be able to avoid it. However, unless you know the size of the array at compile time, it's going to be hard to use a C array without incurring exactly the same indirection. If you do know the size of the array at compile time, you can use a C++11 `std::array`, which will generate identical code to a C array.

Answer (score 2):

I am of the opinion that for many practical purposes it makes no sense to distinguish between C and C++.  When my colleagues bring up the classical rhetoric of "I'm sticking to C because I need to be closer to the metal" what I hear is "I will keep abstraction to a minimum" or, in some unfortunate cases "I know I'm supposed to say that, but I really do not know".

You will take no performance hit whatsoever from a well-designed abstraction.  It could even make your code faster (cf. the typical example of sorting using the C API vs the algorithm API). C++ templates can mean dramatic speed improvements, too.

Having said that, the only answer is "we don't know" or, better: "it depends". That is the case because every snippet of code is different.

As it has been mentioned: the more indirection between your calls and the less data locality will mean the slower your code. This is true in both C and C++. And I repeat myself: do not confuse "I am keeping abstractions to a minimum" with "I'm programming in C".

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question of array vs data members
The main difference is yuo can't use C++ features in C, so if you start coding in C, you won't have C advantages, if you start in C++, its very hard to port to C (assuming proper use)

Comment: An array can be a data member (I am not sure what you mean by that). I don't see how it is "hard" to "port" your programs. If by that you mean "I cannot use a class in C" then you are confusing C++ with Object Oriented Programming. Remember: C++ is not an Object Oriented language, instead it is a *multiparadigm* language (one of the paradigms being OO). You can write a hell lot of code that will compile in both C and C++ without absolutely any modification.

Answer (score 1):

This *is* a premature optimization. :) You need to set performance requirements, implement, then if the requirements are not met, profile and optimize bottlenecks.

What you say about data structures is only partially true. Knowing what data structures to use is only *somewhat* essential, for two main reasons (among others):

1. A well-designed program with a structure divided into distinct, sane, modular components with clear contracts means that if you do change an implementation during optimization later, the code that you change is confined to the smallest possible scope. For example, if you are storing a collection of values that needs to be referenced by some sort of key, don't think "do I use a hash map or a binary tree or a list of some sort or ...", think "what do I need to *do* with this collection?" Hide it behind an API that makes guarantees about functionality, and improve performance later. Perhaps your initial implementation is an array of values that you brute force every time, then later you change it to be a hash table, but *it doesn't matter, not even ahead of time*, because from the outside perspective, its just a collection doing what you said it would do, and it has no impact on your initial design decisions elsewhere.
2. Similar to above, knowing *what* data structure to use is different than knowing what *implementation* to use. You are making a mistake of thinking in too much detail. For example, do not think "hash map" vs. "tree", think "map". Do not think "array" vs. "linked list" vs. "doubly linked list", think "list".

Concentrate on your high level, "OOP" design. Then later, when you are ready to make optimizations, the process will be relatively painless. You don't *need* to know implementation details if your APIs are sane, functional, and well-defined.

Comment: Deciding languages based on performance concerns is generally not considerd premature optimization.
Deciding on optimizing implementation details before you can profile generally is.

Comment: Of course it is premature optimization.  One should code well understood algorithms, which are normally fleshed-out using a high level language for rapid development (eg Python). A bad algorithm will be bad in any language.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum I did not read the OP as trying to decide between two languages. C++ is, for the most part, a full super set of C. GCC and G++ (for example) use the same fundamental back-end for generating binaries, whether you run it in C++ mode or C mode makes no *significant* difference if the code is C. I read the OP as deciding between a C-style approach vs. using language features of C++, and in either case, the high level design is the same, only the syntactic expression is different (e.g. C++ makes representing classes far more convenient).

Comment: @JasonC I was going based on the tags (C is listed) and this, "keep all my data in c code" - code not structs.  But it could just be a typo

Answer (score 0):

There are features in C++ that can make development faster, allowing you to spend more time optimizing
C++ does however give you many more oportunities to write inneficient code, so keep it simple and write it in C++

As to Class vs array:

Getting the 4th int data member is

`this+4*sizeof(int)`

Which is exactly like:

`array+4*sizeof(int)`

Once it gets to machine level - they are just both data loads at an offset

Comment: The main difference may be in data locality; if you use *parallel* arrays you have worse data locality than using arrays of `struct`s if you examine together attributes of each element.